# How do I us std::shared_ptr with box2d?

Tags: c++, box2d, shared-ptr

How do I use a shared_ptr for box2d world? I tried:

```
struct B2DWorld
{
    std::shared_ptr<b2World> world;

    void init()
    {
        b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);
        world(gravity);
    }
};
```

but it gave me error: no match for call to '(std::shared_ptr) (b2Vec2&)' world(gravity);

Comment: Instead of `void init()` use `B2DWorld()`, it's going to be automaticly invoked when `B2DWorld`'s object is created.

Comment: error: expected ';' before 'w'
   world w = std::make_shared(gravity);

Comment: using init() or B2DWorld() is unrelated to my issue though...

Comment: Which is why the suggestion was made as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `make_shared`:

```
void init()
{
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);
    world = std::make_shared<b2World>(gravity);
}
```

or more compactly:

```
    world = std::make_shared<b2World>(b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f));
```

You could use `new b2Vec2(...)` instead of `make_shared`, but that would incur an extra allocation penalty for the `shared_ptr` control structure.

Comment: Welcome to the site, please consider following [this link to the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more acquainted with how to use this site.